# packaging manager for PowerShell script in VSTS

Tags: powershell, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, packaging

We are using VSTS for CI and CD in my team, we got over 40 repositories which are separated projects. but all of them have to run the same PowerShell script in one of their Build steps.

is there something like Nuget for PowerShell that I can use instead of copy the PowerShell file into every single repository?

if yes, anyone can put me in the right direction, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a separate repository for the powershell scripts that you use during your build and release steps, for which you trigger an automatic build (that doesn't build, but just stages the scripts). To access those scripts during build and release, you have a few options:

- For release, you can just include artifacts from the build of the
  scripts repository
- For build, you can either stage the scripts in Azure blob storage
  during the scripts repo build and download them from there, or
- During build, you can use the new "Download Build Artifacts" task
  that can download the scripts from the script repo build.

Comment: thanks - could you please, tell me how to do the second option "For Build, you can either stage..."

Comment: In the build pipeline staging the scripts, use the File Copy task to copy the files to a blob storage account to a container called e.g. BuildScripts. Get a SAS URI for that container and from the build pipeline that needs the scripts, just run a small bit of inline powershell to retrieve the files.